# Meu cálculo parece estar certo, mas a saída do resultado é outra

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, matemática

Desejo fazer uma calculadora do tempo de vida de uma pessoa, baseada no seu ano de nascimento e o ano atual. O usuário deve inserir as duas coisas. Tudo está funcionando, porém, acredito que esteja acontecendo algo no momento do cálculo que eu não consigo identificar o porque: No resultado do tempo de vida da pessoa, o que aparece, são os dados inseridos no campo de dia/mês/ano atuais, e não o resultado da diferença de anos, meses e dias das duas datas.

Código abaixo:

```
package com.example.telakt

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Variaveis para dos componentes da tela
    private lateinit var DataAtualDia : EditText
    private lateinit var DataAtualMes : EditText
    private lateinit var DataAtualAno : EditText

    private lateinit var DataNascDia : EditText
    private lateinit var DataNascMes : EditText
    private lateinit var DataNascAno : EditText

    private lateinit var textResIdade : TextView
    private lateinit var btnCalc : Button

    var ano = 0
    var mes = 0
    var dia = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Relacionar variáveis aos componentes
        DataAtualDia = findViewById(R.id.textDataAtualDia)
        DataAtualMes = findViewById(R.id.textDataAtualMes)
        DataAtualAno = findViewById(R.id.textDataAtualAno)

        DataNascDia = findViewById(R.id.textDataNascDia)
        DataNascMes = findViewById(R.id.textDataNascMes)
        DataNascAno = findViewById(R.id.textDataNascAno)

        textResIdade = findViewById(R.id.textResIdade)

        btnCalc = findViewById(R.id.btnCalc)

        btnCalc.setOnClickListener{calcular()} // Atribuição de uma function para o botão
    }

    // Função do cálculo, e exibição do resultado da conta

    private fun calcular(){
        val dataAtualD = DataAtualDia.text.toString().toInt()
        val dataAtualM = DataAtualMes.text.toString().toInt()
        val dataAtualA = DataAtualAno.text.toString().toInt()

        val dataNascD = DataNascDia.text.toString().toInt()
        val dataNascM = DataNascMes.text.toString().toInt()
        val dataNascA = DataNascAno.text.toString().toInt()

        var diff =  365*dataAtualA + 30*dataAtualM + dataAtualD
                    -365*dataNascA - 30*dataNascM - dataNascD

        ano = diff/365
        diff %= 365

        mes = diff/30
        diff %= 30

        dia = diff

        textResIdade.setText("Tempo de vida: " + ano + " anos, " + mes + " meses e " + dia + " dias.")

            textDataAtualDia.setText("");
            textDataAtualMes.setText("");
            textDataAtualAno.setText("");

            textDataNascDia.setText("");
            textDataNascMes.setText("");
            textDataNascAno.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Custou um pouco a descobrir, mas você foi pego pela falta de ponto-e-vírgula da linguagem. :)

O cálculo de `diff` está levando em consideração apenas a primeira linha do cálculo. A segunda linha está sendo considerada em separado e não está fazendo parte do cálculo. A expressão está gerando um valor que está sendo descartado.

Comment: nem fodendo FQWIUEBFOIUQBWEFOIUQWE

muito obrigado.